# $state params is empty

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a weird issue I don't understand:

I'm using ui-router. Why do I get this results when I console.log in app.run():

```
app.run(function ($state) {
    console.log($state);  // output: Object{params:{sitename:"mysite"},current:{...},... other properties}
    console.log($state.params); // output: Object {}
```

First I print out $state and it has a "params" property which is an object with a property called "sitename".
Then I print out the $state.params property and it's suddenly empty.

Can anyone explain this?

BTW. Also tried this but same result

```
console.log($state["params"]); // output: Object {}
```

Comment: did you tried `$stateParams` service?

Comment: yes i did. $stateParams is also empty. but it does not answer my question!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.

Basically, `console.log($state)` is printing a **reference** to the `$state` dependency, but NOT the actually value of $state. ([Read more here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#statecurrent))

Therefore when you try to access `$state.params`, it returns `undefined`. `$state` will actually have `params` if ui-router finishes routing (after `$stateChangeSuccess`). In this situation we attached custom data to the state object. ([read more about routing and attachment](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#stateconfig))

Answer (score 0):

I met with the same problem.
I suppose could be due to two things:
1. $ stateParams not exist at the time the call
2. $ stateParams not tied to the caller.

Anyway, I solved this problem as follows:

```
.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            $rootScope.toParams = toParams;
        });
}])
```

and use in my object $rootScope.toParams:

```
    params: {
            page: $rootScope.toParams.page,
    }
```